# error: failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0'. Entering rescue mode grub rescue>

Tags: boot, partitioning, grubrescue

Disks:

[image: Disk Window Screenshot]

SMART Data & Self-Tests:

[image: SMART data window screenshot]

Results of `sudo fdisk -l` :

[image: sudo fdisk -l command output]

I was using Ubuntu 16.04, suddenly this grub rescue came on the screen. When I do

```
error: failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0'. 
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> ls (hd))
(hd0): Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is unknown
error: failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0'.
```

I'm getting this issue in office system.

Comment: I suggest you boot 'live' media (eg. Ubuntu install media using "Try Ubuntu") and check the health of your hdd/ssd (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) If the drives health is good, then I'd check the logical health of your file systems (ie. using `fsck` from command line or using GUI tools (`gnome-disks`, `gparted` etc).  If errors are found & fixed, you maybe able to boot the system normally, or else you'll have more clues (health etc) as to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked the system health status, it's showing problem with the hard disk. I got error code as 2000-0151 and validation as 75524

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests**, SMART Data window. Then I can make a recommendation. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. Since I'm not able to boot into OS, I couldn't use SMART test. So I ran the system diagnostics tool in BIOS. I have attached the screenshots of that test results.

Comment: Since you can't boot to the OS, you'll have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, to get the SMART Data window screenshot(s). Also, show me `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: @heynnema I added the screenshots which you requested. Please kindly check and help me

Answer (score 1):

**Your hard disk is failing.** We can try a few things, so keep your fingers crossed. You have two partitions on your hard disk, and both partitions are having problems, which suggests a problem with the MBR partition table, or just the hard disk failing in a very complicated way. **You may have to replace the disk drive.**

**fsck**

This is a file system check. It's the first step to try and diagnose and repair your disk. If we can't get it to run successfully, we'll have to go to the `gparted` step.

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**gparted**

If `fsck` can't be run successfully, we'll try the **Check** option in `gparted`. Start `gparted`. Select `/dev/sdb1`. Go to the **Partition** menu and select **Check**.

If that's not able to fix the errors, assuming that you don't have good data backups, we'll attempt at recovering your data.

In `gparted`, go to the **Device** menu, and select **Attempt Data Rescue**. Follow the instructions to try and copy your data off to an external disk drive.

**bad block**

As a last ditch effort to repair your hard disk, we'll try to bad block the disk, as you do have some bad sectors on the disk. This may fail, and leave your disk in an unknown state.

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdb1` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**sdb2**

This extended partition is also having problems, and the partition is empty, and can be deleted, using `gparted`.

**Update #1:**

The HDD is defective. Replace it.

Comment: Sorry. I tried, when I chose recovery mode, it's not going further. I booted using try ubuntu then did the steps as you suggested but after reboot I'm getting same grub rescue. But sometimes now I'm getting (hd0,msdos1) as file system is ext2. But after I do insmod normal, getting error attempt to read or write from 'hd0'.

Comment: @GangadharS Replace the drive.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your kind concern

Comment: @GangadharS Status please...

Comment: Not able to replace yet, since it's a office system. Thanks