Failure reading sector 0x1036800 from hd0

error:Failure reading sector 0x1036800 from hd0

I turned on the laptop and that message has shown on display ....


replace the harddisk. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248138/error-failure-reading-sector-0x802-from-hd0-entering-rescue-mode-grub-rescue  is the same just a diff. sector.  You can try to follow all these steps https://askubuntu.com/a/1249263/15811  but I would suggest to retrieve the data using a live session if possible and replace the disk
